# Missing required parameters for [Route: berita.update]

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get the parameter `id_berita`, it appears in url, but when i want to show the previous data it can't....

**Controller**

```
class KontenController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $berita = Berita::all();
        return view('backpages/berita', compact('berita'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('backpages.berita_input'); //untuk menampilkan form add
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        request()->validate([
            'id_berita' => 'required',
            'id_kategori' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required',
            'tanggal' => 'required',
            'judul' => 'required',
            'isi' => 'required',
            ]);

            Berita::create($request->all());
            $request->session()->flash('pesan','Berita '.$request['id_berita'].' berhasil disimpan.');
            return redirect()->route('berita.index');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Berita  $berita
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Berita $berita)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Berita  $berita
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Berita $berita)
    {
        // return view('backpages.berita_edit',compact('berita'));
        $berita = Berita::find($berita);
        // return view('backpages.berita_edit')->with('berita',$berita);
        return view('backpages.berita_edit')->with('berita', $berita);

    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Berita  $berita
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Berita $berita)
    {
        request()->validate([
            'username' => 'required',
            'tanggal' => 'required',
            'judul' => 'required',
            'isi' => 'required',
            ]);
            $berita->update($request->all());
            $request->session()->flash('pesan','Berita '.$request['judul'].' berhasil
            diperbarui.');
            return redirect()->route('berita.index');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Berita  $berita
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Berita $berita)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**berita_edit.blade.php** for update process

```
<div class="card card-primary">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title">Edit Berita</h3>
          </div>
          <!-- /.card-header -->
          <!-- form start -->
          <form action="{{route('berita.update')}}" method="POST">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
            {{method_field('PUT')}}  
          <div class="card-body">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="{{ $berita->username }}">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Tanggal</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="tanggal" placeholder="Tanggal" value="{{ $berita->tanggal }}">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Judul</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="judul" placeholder="Judul" value="{{ $berita->judul }}">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Isi</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="isi" value="{{ $berita->isi }}" placeholder="Enter ..."></textarea>
                </div>

            <!-- /.card-body -->

            <div class="card-footer">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
```

For displaying data

```
 <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
            <table class="table table-hover text-nowrap">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>id_Berita</th>
                  <th>id_Kategori</th>
                  <th>Username</th>
                  <th>Tanggal</th>
                  <th>Judul</th>
                  <th>Isi</th>
                  <th colspan="2" style="text-align:left">Opsi</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                @foreach($berita as $data)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$data -> id_berita}}</td>
                    <td>{{$data -> id_kategori}}</td>
                    <td>{{$data -> username}}</td>
                    <td>{{$data -> tanggal}}</td>
                    <td>{{$data -> judul}}</td>
                    <td>{{$data -> isi}}</td>
                    <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-block btn-info" href="{{ route('berita.edit', $data -> id_berita) }}"?>Edit</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-block btn-info" href="#"?>Hapus</a>
                    </td>



                </tr>
                @endforeach
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
```

Comment: add this in your blade: `<form action="{{route('berita.update', $berita)}}" method="POST">`

Comment: it still dont work bro, ive try add $berita -> id_berita
which id_berita came from my database coloumn name

Comment: post your route

Comment: im using resource, is that possible to use post, im sorrry for asking that, im realy beginner

Comment: try this: `<form action="{{route('berita.update', $berita)}}" method="POST">` `{{method_field("PATCH")}}`

Comment: it doesnt pass the id, become blank

Answer (score 0):

You have to change action like this

```
<form action="{{route('berita.update',['berita'=>$berita->id])}}" method="POST">


<a class="btn btn-block btn-info" href="{{ route('berita.edit', ['berita'=>$data->id_berita]) }}"?>Edit</a>
```

Comment: another error appear
Property [id_berita] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\BISProject\resources\views\backpages\berita_edit.blade.php) 
ive search in community for fixing this, but nothing happend, just the same

Comment: Please share your `route` @fahmizikrul

Comment: Route::resource('berita' , 'KontenController')->name('*','berita');

Comment: <td>{{$data ->id_berita}}</td> - i did it
and then it back again
Missing required parameters for [Route: berita.edit] [URI: admin/berita/{beritum}/edit]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\BISProject\resources\views\backpages\berita.blade.php) -

Comment: i was using adding some new guard in config - auth.php , is it take any effect?

Comment: This is the problem `beritum` as `berita`. Use `berita` then your problem solve. I update my asnwer @fahmizikrul. Now check please. Use `beritum or berita` in your `<a tag` then check which one is correct

Comment: i dont know why it still not working
what is beritum? i never wrote that before

Comment: if i see the url in my browser, it pass the id
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/berita/3/edit

but when i want to show previous data in edit page, it shows nothing
im using value="{{ $berita->id }}"

Comment: `php artisan route:list` then check your route. My solution works fine for me always. First I try my own then answer any question.